# Два Selecta нужно подгрузить данные во второй select зависимости от первого

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ситуация такая пишу сайт на Asp.net MVC 5 есть форма создания животного, есть два Select в одном вид животного а в втором порода. Ну и нужно реализовать чтоб при изменение первого, в второй подгружались данные з бази. Вот как я формирую эти Select по дефолту.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, ViewBag.type as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Species, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Species, ViewBag.species as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Species, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Как я понимаю нужно это сделать лыбо в JQuery, или в AJAX. Но сам не знаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуста

Answer (score 1):

Здесь дело не в селектах, а в том, что тебе нужно отследить событие изменения значения первого выпадающего списка, в функции-хендлере взять его значение, сделать запрос на сервер (аякс), на сервере достать данные для второго выпадающего списка (селектом или как-то еще) и по success в aякс-запросе заполнить второй Ddl полученными значениями.

На клиенте **примерно** так:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectListItem[]    
{
 new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text1", Value = "0" }, 
 new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text2", Value = "1" }
},
 new { @onchange="onChange(this.value)" })


<script>
function onChange(val)
{
 var typeVal = $('#Type').val()
 $.post( '@Url.Action("GetSpecies","Controller")', {typeVal : typeVal }
  function( data ) {
       var select = $("#Type");
       select.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                        select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: data.Value,
                            text: data.Text
                        }));
                    });
  });
}
</script>
```